# memory exception while training SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, training-data

to train SVM classifier i use features extracted from different images ( each image have number of features =! of other images beacause i use SLIC superpixeland from each region i extract 20 features) after preparing the TraingMatData and LabelsMat i got this [bug](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxn1ltn3tjy8x58/training1.PNG?dl=0) whith a notification : Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000E5176E2740. I couldn't understand what's the wrong in my code here's my code and i'm waiting your helps.

```
int main()
{
    /// training 
    cv::Mat image;
    //load the features from files 

    Mat trainingDataMat(47,27000, CV_32FC1);

    float features[1350][20];
    float labels[47] = {-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,... i delet the rest of them};

    vector<int> size;
    for (int i = 1; i < 48; i++) {
        vector<float> numbers;
        //Mat features(1200, 20, CV_32FC1);

        string filename = "D:\\mémoire\\training\\trainingData\\featuers";
        filename = filename + std::to_string(i);
        filename = filename + ".txt";
        int size_e = 0;
        //read(numbers, filename);
        ifstream in(filename);
        float number;
        string aa;

        while (in.good()) {

            getline(in, aa, ',');
            number = strtod(aa.c_str(), NULL);
            numbers.push_back(number);
            size_e = size_e + 1;
            //features.push_back(number);
        }

        in.close();

        size.push_back(size_e);
        int pp = numbers.size()/ 20;

        int d = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < 1350; p++) {
            for (int p1 = 0; p1 < 20; p1++) {
                if (pp <= d) {
                    features[p][p1] = 0;
                }
                else {
                    //features.at<uchar>(p, p1) = numbers[d];
                    features[p][p1] = numbers[d];
                    d++;
                }
            }
        }
        cv::Mat A(1350, 20, CV_32FC1, features);
        trainingDataMat.push_back(A.reshape(1, 1));
    }

        Mat labelsMat(47, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //seting the SVM

        Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
        // edit: the params struct got removed,

        svm->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
        svm->setKernel(ml::SVM::RBF);
        svm->setGamma(100);

        //Mat trainData; // one row per feature

        svm->train(trainingDataMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);
        // ...
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this program, one line at a time what observations did you make? Your debugger will easily tell you where the memory exception occured, and why. This is what a debugger is for. That it's job. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. No exceptions.

Comment: i had memory exception before and i resolut them but this is my first time  with classifier and training so i don't have a background in this kind of exception and this is why i shared my problem

Comment: Well, sounds like you have an excellent opportunity right now to learn how to use a debugger, and be able to figure out this problem by yourself. Don't you think that knowing how to effectively figure out and fix bugs using a debugger is much better than asking for help on stackoverflow.com, every time your program crashes for some reason?

Comment: ok i have no problem it's better for me to increase my background. So give me hit how i begin beacause i spent a lot of time with out knowing what's the problem !

Comment: by the way thanks for no help ;) and please why wasting time if you will noyt help ?!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It is not a waste of time to give you the best advice anyone can possibly give you, here. Don't you think it makes much more sense to learn how to effectively debug on your own code, instead of running to stackoverflow.com every time you can't figure it out? Instead of waiting hours, or even days, before someone might come along with an answer -- if one ever comes along -- it shouldn't take more than 10-15 minutes to walk through the code, one line at a time, with a debugger, and figure out exactly what's happening. Learning how to use a debugger was the best thing I ever did.

Comment: i posted my bug because i couldn't find the solution. by the way someone gave me the solution in opencv forum and i could wast 7 days without solving this problem. I'm doing a project for my degree and i have to save time that's it and when i got stuck in problem and wast a lot of time then i post my problem. thanks for your answer and for your understand

Comment: ... and if you already knew how to use a debugger you would've found the solution yourself in 10-15 minutes, instead of posting it here, and waiting several days for someone to help you. As I wrote in my first comment: knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. And now you understand exactky why that is. Perhaps you'll now take the time learn how to use a debugger, so the next time you can figure everything out by yourself.